# Overloading WebAPI controller with 2 Get methods

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

I have webapi controller with 2 action methods like so:

```
public List<AlertModel> Get()
{
    return _alertService.GetAllForUser(_loginService.GetUserID());
}

public AlertModel Get(int id)
{
    return _alertService.GetByID(id);
}
```

However, when I make a request to `api/alerts` I get the following error:

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of
>   non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method
>   'ekmSMS.Common.Models.AlertModel Get(Int32)' in
>   'ekmSMS.Web.Api.AlertsController'. An optional parameter must be a
>   reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional
>   parameter.

I have the following route set up in `global.asax`:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute("Api", "api/{controller}/{id}", new { id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Should this type of overloading work? And if it should what am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

Although this question is about WebAPI, the controllers are part of a MVC3 project, these are the other `MapRoutes`:

```
routes.MapRoute("Templates", "templates/{folder}/{name}", new { controller = "templates", action = "index", folder = "", name = "" });    
routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { controller = "app", action = "index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Comment: Could we see all your MapHttpRoutes ? Sometimes it could be some interference within them.

Comment: @user854301 question is about Web API, not MVC.

Comment: that's pretty interesting cuz the route parameter whose default value is `UrlParameter.Optional` is removed if it is not supplied so, action selection logic should have picked up the `Get()` action method here (for any request which comes to *api/alerts*). I'll try to repro the error.

Comment: I answered below. Don't use `UrlParameter.Optional` for any Web API route. Use `RouteParameter.Optional` instead. Keep in mind that don't use anything under `System.Web.Mvc` for any Web API code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that you used `UrlParameter.Optional` (which is an ASP.NET MVC specific type) instead of `RouteParameter.Optional`. Change your route as below and then it should work:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    "Api",
    "api/{controller}/{id}",
    new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```